# UEFI Secure Boot Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, uefi

I've got a CentOS setup with UEFI Secure Boot turned on.  I'm working on debugging a set of BIOS tools that were developed quite some time ago.  However when Secure Boot is turned on it appears user applications are not allow to get higher privilege levels any more.

Essentially I have a kernel module that maps a virtual to physical memory buffer which is used to communicate to the BIOS.  The buffer is setup and a software SMI is called so the BIOS can retrieve it, process it, and put the results back into the buffer.

I'm trying to figure out how this can still be done with Secure Boot enabled?  The kernel module can still setup the buffer, but it appears like I'm unable to call into my character device setup by the kernel module.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: What??  I am developing a kernel mode driver for Linux!  What part of development does this not apply to?

Comment: @Jeff: Stackoverflow is predominately frequented by people working on higher levels of the software stack. Additionally, a majority of questions asked on the UEFI tag _are_ off-topic, so people can be a bit trigger happy. By including tags 'linux' and to some extent 'kernel'. you have put your question in front of people who likely don't have the experience required to see that your question isn't a "how do I boot my computer" one, but a valid on-topic one for stackoverflow. That said, your question could be improved with the addition of some code examples.

Comment: I'm new to UEFI, but I'm pretty sure the secure boot options are meant to prevent unauthenticated user code from attaining kernel privileges and calling the UEFI API. I suppose you either you authenticate the code using the kernel's key or install it on the firmware as a UEFI driver, so it loads before the OS boot loader loads. I think the root user should be able to sign the code as a system driver, allowing it to make UEFI API calls... I wish I could actually help, but I don't know enough to be practical.